# B2B/Powertools Spartacus 3.3 - Missing "Reorder", "Cancel" and "Return" options in MyAccount

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Successfully build Commerce 2011_7 with Spartacus 3.3 last week (using the standard instructions for B2B Commerce) and all appears to function on initial tests.

This week, I've gone to test the Standard Order Flows with mark.rivers@pronto-hw.com and noticed that the "Self Service" buttons that typically appear against a placed order in My Account are missing, and these are definitely there in the JSP Storefront and earlier versions of Spartacus.

I'm able to follow the instructions but not a developer so asking if anyone knows whats causing them to 'not appear' and could help me get them back please - have supplied a screenshot with the Console open as well.

The two lines in the console that concerned me were:

```
spartacus-storefront.js:18398 No component implementation found for the CMS component type 'AccountOrderDetailsOverviewComponent'.
 Make sure you implement a component and register it in the mapper.

spartacus-storefront.js:18398 No component implementation found for the CMS component type 'AccountOrderDetailsReorderComponent'.
 Make sure you implement a component and register it in the mapper.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mZQ4.png)

Comment: Would you be able to please add some screenshots of the current and previous versions to compare the missing buttons?

Comment: Hi @CaineRotherham - My B2C isnt working and I've deleted by old B2B so this screenshot is taken from the Public B2C Electronics store (https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/) :

https://sap-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/p/arun_mistry/EbBjfqDCZptLvbQX_5S9tsgBQVtwe2g1qYpjBSYSRRWT9A?e=69BmsN

You can see the "cancel button" - I don't have Admin access to Despatch it to then show the "Return" button.

Answer (score 0):

order self service was added in 1.4 but you need release 2005.
see https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/cancellations-and-returns/

it's possible that with installation of 3.3, the cancel/returns code wasn't installed? we transitioned to many smaller libraries for 3.3. but also you need cms content in the backend (which looks like you have).

Comment: Thanks Bill, unfortunately both those ImpEx snippets supplied error in the HAC - I'm running Spartacus 3.3 on Commerce 2011 - would the ImpEx differ for newer versions?

INSERT_UPDATE CMSFlexComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];visible;# unknown attribute '$contentCV' in header 'INSERT_UPDATE CMSFlexComponent'
,,,,unknown attribute '$contentCV' in header 'INSERT_UPDATE CMSFlexComponent';;AccountOrderDetailsActionsComponent;true